# Reusing Axis Scale overwrites set domain

Tags: javascript, inheritance, d3.js, overwrite

I have multiple Graphs on one page that all supposed to have the same size, so I thouth instead copy-pasting a lot of code for each Graph, reusing the common setting might be a good idea:

```js
var xAxisScaleTime = d3.scaleTime().range([0, graph_width ]);
var xAxisScaleLinear = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, graphwidth ]);

var yAxisScaleLin = d3.scaleLinear().range( [ graph_height , 0]);
var yAxisScaleLog = d3.scaleLog().range( [  graph_height , 0]);

//etc...
```

The domains of each graph might be different. So I set them up like this:

```js
// Most Graphs will share the same Time-Domain
var GraphT_X = xAxisScaleTime.domain([ starttime, endtime]); 

// Graphs have different Domains for Y
var Graph1_Y = yAxisScaleLin.domain([[ Graph_1_min, Graph_1_max]);
var Graph2_Y = yAxisScaleLin.domain([[ Graph_2_min, Graph_2_max]);

//etc...
```

But then I set up multiple Graphs with those I end up with the same:

[image: How it looks like]

```js
//For the sake of short code I skipped Viewbox, widht, height, classes, etc. here


var Graph_1 = d3.select("#Graph1")
              .append("svg")
              .append("g");

// add the X Axis Graph_1
Graph_1.append("g")
       .call( d3.axisBottom( GraphT_X )
            .ticks(d3.timeDay)
            .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d.%m")));

// add the Y Axis Graph_1
Graph_1.append("g")
       .call( d3.axisLeft(Graph1_Y) // <--- Using first Y-Axis here
            .ticks(5, ".0f"));

var Graph_2 = d3.select("#Graph2")
              .append("svg")
              .append("g");

// add the X Axis Graph_1
Graph_2.append("g")
       .call( d3.axisBottom( GraphT_X )
            .ticks(d3.timeDay)
            .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d.%m")));

// add the Y Axis Graph_2
Graph_2.append("g")
       .call( d3.axisLeft( Graph2_Y ) // <--- Using different/second Y-Axis here
            .ticks(8, ".0f"));
```

This seems as clean and pretty as it can get. But the browser always renders the same Graph, as if `Graph1_Y` gets overwritten as I define `Graph2_Y`.

Its supposed to look like this:
[image: Desired Result]

This is probably no error in D3 but some javascript inheritance.
Anyone got an idea of how I can fix this while reusing the scale-variables like `yAxisScaleLin`?
Because defining 10+ times the same range Axis is is somehow not as clear as I'd like to have my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems as clean and pretty as it can get. But the browser always renders the same Graph, as if Graph1_Y gets overwritten as I define Graph2_Y

That is exactly what you are doing here:

```
// Graphs have different Domains for Y
var Graph1_Y = yAxisScaleLin.domain([[ Graph_1_min, Graph_1_max]);
var Graph2_Y = yAxisScaleLin.domain([[ Graph_2_min, Graph_2_max]);
```

`yAxisScaleLin.domain([values])` both modifies and returns itself: `yAxisScaleLin` - it does not return a new scale object. So both `Graph1_Y` and `Graph2_Y` are references for the same scale object.

**Possible Solution**

Your code would work if .domain() returned a new scale instead of the same scale it was called on, which is what you were assuming would happen. However, there is a method that lets you return a new scale object based on an existing scale:

```
 var graph1_Y = yAxisCaleLin.copy().domain(...
```

The `scale.copy()` method returns a copy of the scale it is called on, including a copy of all its properties. Then you can set the domain to a new value.

```js
    var scale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0,1]); 
    
    var a = scale.copy().domain([0, 1]);
    var b = scale.copy().domain([2, 3]);
    
    console.log(a.domain().toString());
    console.log(b.domain().toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that `Graph1_Y` and `Graph2_Y` were only references. Is this a common behavior of JS and/or D3?
Your solution works flawlessly! This will save me so much Code!

Comment: For D3, when using most of their methods, *most* D3 objects, like scales, force simulations, selections, etc, are built to return themselves as opposed to copies of themselves, this lets you avoid having to redeclare the variable every time you modify it after its initial declaration. So at any time, you can just use `xScale.domain([values])` instead of `xScale = xScale.domain([values])` - there are times when you want a new object though, so there are methods such as `.copy()` for scales.